# manifest wiki page issues

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was just looking into the use of the `<export>` tag and noticed a couple of problems on the  [wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/Manifest) for manifest.xml:

- There is an error message:

  `Unsupported navigation scheme 'Menus/ROSFilesystemConcepts'!`

at the top of the page

- Clicking on the "manifest.xml tags reference" link takes you to a [page](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rospkg/html/manifest_xml.html) titled "ROS packages Fuerte documentation" which doesn't seem correct given that Fuerte isn't out yet.

I feel a vague sense of guiltiness reporting a bug on answers.ros.org--probably it should go on trac but I'm feeling lazy. If in fact it would be better to report it there, it would be nice if every wiki page had a link somewhere that got you to the right part of trac to report wiki problems...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12867/manifest-wiki-page-issues/) by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2264 on 2012-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ticketed at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3835 and meta complaint at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3834

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2012-02-02**:
Thanks Tully!